# In skimage, how to get cmap from one generated image, and use it in another image?

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-image

If I plot two images with **cmap="gray"**:

- on *Im1* (left), the tile with value 0.1 is light grey
- On *Im2* (right), the tiles are all defined with value 0.1, but there are all black

So how do I obtain the same light grey on *Im2* ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Im1 = np.array([[0.1,0.2],[0.02,0.002]])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(Im1, cmap="gray")

Im2 = np.array([[0.1,0.1],[0.1,0.1]])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(Im2, cmap="gray")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the same `Normalize` object on both subplots, like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

Im1 = np.array([[0.1,0.2],[0.02,0.002]])
Im2 = np.array([[0.1,0.1],[0.1,0.1]])

_min = min(t.min() for t in [Im1, Im2])
_max = max(t.max() for t in [Im1, Im2])
norm = Normalize(vmin=_min, vmax=_max)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(Im1, cmap="gray", norm=norm)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(Im2, cmap="gray", norm=norm)

plt.show()
```

[image]